# Compiling the PHP stack with Clang

Tags: php, llvm, clang

Is it possible yet to compile a full PHP stack - say Apache, PHP, Postgres and enough of the more commonly used libraries to cover ninety percent of sites - with Clang into LLVM bitcode? If so, are there any instructions available on how to do it starting with an out-of-the-box Ubuntu setup?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why to bitcode, rather than machine code?

Comment: With a view to running an analyzer on the code.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache, PHP and Postgres can be compiled by Clang, which means they can also be compiled into LLVM bitcode. I can't give you particular steps to achieve this, since it depends on build system. Anyway, this involves adding `-femit-llvm` flag to compilation line and, probably, using `llvm-link` as linker.

Be aware that at least PHP have inline assembly code, on which your analyzer may choke.

**UPDATE**:

Nice tool to compile code using arbitrary build systems to LLVM IR is [gllvm](https://github.com/SRI-CSL/gllvm). In short, you just use `gclang`/`gclang++` instead of `gcc/g++` and then running `get-bc` on the resulting binary.